# jQuery: Issue with internal caching

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on UI improvements of a legacy system (jQuery version: 1.6.2).

I have a HTML table which can be represented in 2 different states: expanded and collapsed. This is achieved by adding specific CSS class (FFA-hc) on particular  elements.
When user is expanding the table all elements with 'FFA-hc' class becomes visible using jQuery's show() method: `$(".FFA-hc").show();` Collapse works vice-versa: `$(".FFA-hc").hide();`

User is able to add/remove rows to/from this table.
Add: `$('tbody > tr:eq(' + (FFAs.rows.length - 2) + ')', FFAs).before(String.format(template, index));`
Remove: `$('tbody > tr:eq(' + index + ')', FFAs).remove();`

The problem starts after following steps:

1. User has expanded the table
2. A row has been removed
3. User is trying to collapse the table

Result is a Javascript error in jQuery code: Unable to get property 'jQuery16207024853786526762' of undefined or null reference.

What I have found so far:
At step 1 for all elements with 'FFA-hc' class the new attribute 'jQuery16207024853786526762' has been added with integer value (sequence number).
At step 2 some of such elements were removed from DOM.
At step 3 jQuery is trying to get an element which no longer exist in DOM and fails with error.

Is it a bug in a jQuery?
Please advise how can I get rid of this error.

P.S. Upgrade of jQuery is not a best option in my case.

EDIT:
The error occurs in 'data' method of a jQuery.extend object at line 1455 of full jQuery 1.6.2 source:
if ((!id || (pvt && id && !cache[id][internalKey])) && getByName && data === undefined) {
    return;
}
The problematic part of the if clause is `!cache[id][internalKey]` - the `cache[id]` is undefined

Comment: Please show the exact line of code that causes the error.  Also, it is possible to trace through the jQuery call where the error occurs in the debugger and see exactly what is unhappy.  That's probably the only way to truly get to the bottom of what is happening.  Your jQuery version is pretty old and many, many, many bugs have been fixed since 1.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have compared the jQuery's v1.6.2 source with latest v1.11.1 and it lacks one additional check in if clause: `!cache[id]`.
As an upgrade of jQuery is not allowed I have only updated the if statement
from:
`if ((!id || (pvt && id && !cache[id][internalKey])) && getByName && data === undefined) { return; }`
to:
`if ((!id || !cache[id] || (pvt && id && !cache[id][internalKey])) && getByName && data === undefined) { return; }`